# Is the BlackBerry code signing service down at the moment?

Tags: blackberry, code-signing, blackberry-jde

My BlackBerry code signing has started to fail with an “Error connecting to web signer from proxy”.  [Searching the web](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Code-signing-web-service-down/m-p/30492) seems to indicate this is a problem with the BlackBerry code signing service.  Is anybody else hitting this at the moment?

Wireshark indicates I am getting a response from www.rim.net with the error message in.

Request:

> POST /Websigner/servlet/Runtime
>   HTTP/1.1 Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache User-Agent:
>   Java/1.6.0_21 Host: www.rim.net
>   Accept: text/html, image/gif,
>   image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
>   Connection: keep-alive Content-type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Content-Length: 268
>   CSC File according to the specs for the Signature Tool.
>   Mon Nov 08 19:42:17 EST 2010  Command=Signature Request

Response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 09 Nov 2010
>   00:39:22 GMT Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>   '#CSC File according to the specs for the Signature Tool.
>   '#Mon Nov 08 19:39:22 EST 2010 Version=0 Error=Error connecting to
>   web signer from proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sticky about this on the BB dev boards: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Signing-Server-Scheduled-Downtime-for-Upgrades/td-p/630837

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that.  They really should make the error message to say it is scheduled downtime and when the service is expected to be restored...

Comment: -1 Unfortunately this link doesn't get updated nearly as often as the server is offline.

Answer (score 8):

You can check out the web page that keeps track of the Blackberry signing servers:

http://isthesigningserverdown.com

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, this twitter feed is useful.  It confirms the signing servers keep going down at the moment, and the BlackBerry sticky in the other answer doesn't say there is any scheduled maintenance.

Comment: Please update this.. As, the above link are broken now.. http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-about-isthesigningserverdown/m-p/2799877#U2799877