# Strange BlackBerry Packaging/Signing Issue

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

I have been getting this strange packaging/signing error for the entire day (23 Aug 2012). It seems more like signing problem though, since it packages fine when it does not need signing. The progress goes up to 99% and just stays there forever.

When RRT is required, it will be RRT waiting for response. When RRT is not required, the next in line (in this case, RBB) waits for response. E-mails are sent back confirming the signing, but the packaging is not completed and it is unusable.

I have tried:
1. Re-installing the code signing key.
2. Re-installing the entire Eclipse & BlackBerry Plug-in.
3. Requesting and re-installing a completely new signing key.
4. Ask the BlackBerry Support Forum (where graveyards are actually more lively).

None of them works, by the way. Oh, and I should add that, without any modifications whatsoever, the signing process worked fine yesterday.

So I think I should try my luck here. Please help.

Comment: I met such situations before. The reason are RIM servers, they do not work as good as expected. Just wait when servers start work correctly. On my experience it was about 1-2 days.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129532/is-the-blackberry-code-signing-service-down-at-the-moment there are links where people monitor rim signing servers

Comment: Unfortunately, even RIM Servers reported as `ok`, they do not always work properly upon a signing process. I checked "are signing servers down"  website and got - "all right" report, but I still had signing problem, until servers worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

What version of BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse and BlackBerry Java SDK are you using?  Some of the older versions have conflicts with JDK 7.0, which causes the SignatureTool to hang while receiving signatures from the RIM signing servers.  You can read more about it here:

[SignatureTool Stops Responding While Signing](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/SignatureTool-Stops-Responding-While-Signing/ta-p/1286833)